# Reporting Services não traz linha com valores zerados

Tags: sql, services, reporting-services

Estou fazendo um relatório de situação dos alunos por modalidade de curso, onde preciso exibir uma matriz, mesmo que todos os valores estejam zerados. Ao filtrar um determinado curso, o qual não contém a modalidade "À distância", a linha que deveria aparecer com todos os totalizadores zerados, simplesmente não aparece porque estou agrupando por modalidade e por tipo de público, e ao adicionar os row group a linha zerada simplesmente não é exibida no relatório. Ao excluir o agrupamento a linha é exibida, mas eu perco a informação de Público. Alguém sabe como resolver isto? Há uma forma de exibir os agrupamentos mesmo com valor 0 nas linhas? Segue abaixo as telas:

Row Group:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF7Rm.png

Sem o row group:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK1Xs.png

Com o Row Group (simplesmente some a linha da modalidade Distância):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCZAP.png

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver deixando os textos fixos das modalidades e tipos de público, e no número de vagas inseri um if. Para o público Interno coloquei:

=Iif(Fields!nme_tipo_publico.Value = "Interno",Iif(Fields!VAGA.Value = 0,0,Fields!VAGA.Value),0)

Para o público externo, substituí o valor "Interno" por "Externo. Fiz isso para todas as matrizes e deu certo.